# Solver/Algorithms for Pseudo-Convex Optimization Problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a question concerning optimization of pseudo-convex functions.
Explicitly, the problem is given by

$\mathrm{min}_x f(x)$ with $g(x) \leq 0$

where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are pseudo-convex functions.

I know that one can in principle think about many algorithms especially suited for such problems. However, I do not want to write a solver myself, rather I would like to use one of the standard solvers. Of course, all general purpose-solvers for non-linear optimization will do the job. 
However I guess that there will be huge differences in performance, depending on how well the optimizer uses the nice properties of pseudo-convex functions.

Does anybody have suggestions for algorithms/solvers that will perform well in the case of such pseudo-convex problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $g$ has to be convex for your optimization problem to be called pseudo-convex

Comment: Ah, ok. I was not aware of this semantic problem. Foremost, I am interest in the problem where $g$ is only pseudo-convex. Within some approximation $f$ and $g$ are even pseudo-linear. Are there any solvers specifically designed for such problems? On the other hand, are there solvers specifically designed for problems where $g$ is convex?

Comment: Quasiconvex problems can be solved via the bisection method. When $g$ is pseudoconvex, you should be able to reformulate $g(x) \leq 0$ to an inequality with a convex function.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!